# materialized view is refreshing externally as external task in php.Is it needed?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, materialized-views

I am new to PostgreSQL, I am refreshing the materialized view before calling it from PHP code for reporting purpose. Is it needed?

Comment: if you want a fresh data set, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you [have](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) to refresh it to

> replace the contents of a materialized view

Comment: Thanks for the support